# Pass Variable from Excel Macro to .vbs file

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have an excel button with a macro. The code simply stores the path of the workbook in a vaiable names 'MyCompletePath' and then runs a .vbs file. The code is:

```
MyCompletePath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

'Run VBS file
Shell "wscript C:\Users\name\Desktop\vb.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```

I want to pass the variable 'MyCompletePath' from the excel file to the file which is executed using the last line.

I made some searches but didn't fully understand what their solutions do. Maybe someone can tell me how to do it.

UPDATE/EDIT: I'm now having a problem with the filepath after Shell "wscript. It has spaces in the folder name. How can I get it to work with spaces in the name?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing argument from vba to vbs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376588/passing-argument-from-vba-to-vbs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include command line arguments after the path to your VBS file.  For example:

```
Shell "wscript C:\Users\name\Desktop\vb.vbs BlahBlahBlah", vbNormalFocus
```

Then inside your VBS script, you can access them using the WScript.Arguments collection.  For example:

```
MsgBox WScript.Arguments(0)
```

would pop up a message box displaying "BlahBlahBlah".

For a file path, as you indicated, which might include spaces and thus would be treated as multiple arguments to the script, I would include the argument in quotes, like this:

```
Shell "wscript C:\Users\name\Desktop\vb.vbs ""this has multiple words""", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: If I entered the variable name in the quotes it would send the variable name and not the value it has right?

EDIT: Yes, the quotes cannot hold variables. Only strings. Any way around that?

Comment: You can do this: Shell "wscript C:\Users\name\Desktop\vb.vbs """ & strMyPath & """", vbNormalFocus

Comment: Or this might be easier to read:  Shell "wscript C:\Users\name\Desktop\vb.vbs " & Chr(34) & strMyPath & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus.  Chr(34) returns the double-quote character.

Answer (score 1):

based on [passing argument from vba to vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376588/passing-argument-from-vba-to-vbs)

When I write that within the vba:

```
Sub Macro1()

MyCompletePath = "toto"

Shell "wscript D:\\vb.vbs " & MyCompletePath

End Sub
```

and this in vb.vbs

```
MsgBox("Hello " & WScript.Arguments(0))
```

I do get "Hello toto"

Comment: Worked great, only thing is that the text behind WScript.Arguments(0) would stop at an spaces for if you had:

MyCompletePath = "to to"

MsgBox("Hello " & WScript.Arguments(0))

It would return here: "to"

Comment: roryap answer holds the solution for that : add escaped double quotes around each spaced argument so that it is read as a consistent whole :)