# Removing diachritics accents from words

Tags: vbscript, arguments

Please help me to change this code to accept a parameter in the command line

Function to remove accents - diachritics.

```
Function EliminarAcentos(texto)

    Dim i, s1, s2
    s1 = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïòóôõöùúûü"
    s2 = "AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUaaaaaaceeeeiiiiooooouuuu"
    If Len(texto) <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(s1)
            texto = Replace(texto, Mid(s1,i,1), Mid(s2,i,1))
        Next
    End If

    EliminarAcentos = texto

End Function
```

I need to run the script like this:

```
>remove_accents Dídímênsô
Didimenso
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806713/can-i-pass-an-argument-to-a-vbscript-vbs-file-launched-with-cscript

Comment: I put this line in the end of the script:

Wscript.Arguments(0)

and run the script like this:

> cscript remove_acentos.vbs ênfase
 
But I get this message;

remove_acentos.vbs(1, 36) Erro de compilação do Microsoft VBScript: ')' esperado

Answer (score 0):

The error you mention in your comment ("remove_acentos.vbs(1, 36) Erro de compilação do Microsoft VBScript: ')' esperado") is not caused by the code you published.

This

```
Option Explicit

Function EliminarAcentos(texto)

    Dim i, s1, s2
    s1 = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïòóôõöùúûü"
    s2 = "AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUaaaaaaceeeeiiiiooooouuuu"
    If Len(texto) <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(s1)
            texto = Replace(texto, Mid(s1,i,1), Mid(s2,i,1))
        Next
    End If

    EliminarAcentos = texto

End Function

Dim texto : texto = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïòóôõöùúûü"
If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then texto = WScript.Arguments(0)

WScript.Echo EliminarAcentos(texto)
```

compiles and runs successfully - to demonstrate the use of .[Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6y04sbb%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).